# Remove punctuation from a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, data-cleaning

Here's my `series` which had been tokenized and removed stop words:

```
0        [laptop, sits, 4, stars, similarly, priced, co...
1        [ordered, monitor, wanted, makeshift, area, po...
2        [monitor, great, deal, price, size, ., use, of...
3        [bought, height, adjustment, ., swivel, abilit...
4        [worked, month, died, ., 5, calls, hp, support...
                               ...                        
30618                                        [great, deal]
30619                                  [pour, le, travail]
30620                                      [business, use]
30621                                         [good, size]
30622    [pour, mon, ordinateur.plus, grande, image.vra...
Name: text_body, Length: 30623, dtype: object
```

I want to remove punctuation from the above series. I had tried something like this

```
filtered_text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',str(series))
```

the result comes out as a string.

2 questions I have.

1. is there a way to convert the `filtered_text` string to back to list or series?
2. are there better ways to Remove punctuation from the original series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ideally remove `punctuations` from a series like this:

```
filtered_text = s.str.replace('[^\w\s]','')
```

where `s` is your series.

**Explanation:**

You first convert your series to string by `.str` then apply the `replace` regex.
Now you don't have to worry about converting it back to `series` again.

Comment: I tried your way. and it seems the `filtered_text` result becomes full of `NaN` values. is there any way I can fix this? anyway, thanks for the answer, much appreciated.